# How to bind value from database to Dropdown List in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to bind a dropdown list from database in mvc3.

I have two tables.
**tblEmp:**
EmpID (pk),
EName,
Age,
Address,
EmailID,
DeptID (fk).

**tblDept**
DeptID (pk),
DeptName,
DeptHead.

I am trying to bind create an Employee application with the basic details of an employee
Name, Age, Address, EmailID, and Dept Name. I am trying to bind the Dept Name dropdownlist from the other table.

**This is my Model:**

```
namespace MvcEmployeeApplication.Models
{

   public class UandPcompare
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public string EName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string EmailID { get; set; }
    public int DeptID { get; set; }
    public string DeptName { get; set; }
    public string DeptHead { get; set; }

    public IList<SelectListItem> Drp_DeptNames { get; set; }
}
}
```

**This is Controller:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        FillDeptName();        
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(tblEmployee tblEmp)
    {
        test.Entry(tblEmp).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
        test.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }

    public ActionResult FillDeptName()
    {
        UandPcompare filldeptNme = new UandPcompare();            
        filldeptNme.Drp_DeptNames = (from DptName in test.tblDepts
                                     select new SelectListItem()
                                     {
                                         Text = DptName.DeptName,
                                         Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)DptName.DeptID)
                                     }).ToList<SelectListItem>();
        return View("Create");
    }
```

**This is MyView:**

```
@model MvcEmployeeApplication.Models.UandPcompare
@{
ViewBag.title = "Edit";
}
<h2> Create </h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<fieldset>
<legend> Create </legend>

<div>
  Employee ID:  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmpID)
</div>
<div>
  Employee Name:  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EName)
</div>
<div>
  Email-ID:  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailID)
</div>
<div>
  Address: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
</div>
<div>
  Dept Name: @Html.DropDownList("DeptName", Model.Drp_DeptNames, "Select")
</div>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
```

```
<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Index", "Index");
</div>
```

Comment: I think the best way to do this is write a javascript which would call an `Action` method which in turn will return a Json array of object. You can then bind these to the drop down using JQUERY.

Comment: Dont think its good idea, whats need of ajax ajax when he can pass SelectList from action only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not able to get what error are you getting.

You are not passing any model to your view.

```
public ActionResult FillDeptName()
    {
        UandPcompare filldeptNme = new UandPcompare();            
        filldeptNme.Drp_DeptNames = (from DptName in test.tblDepts
                                     select new SelectListItem()
                                     {
                                         Text = DptName.DeptName,
                                         Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)DptName.DeptID)
                                     }).ToList<SelectListItem>();
        return View("Create",filldeptNme);//pass model to view here
    }
```